# How to Remove Text After H2 element

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having an issue removing the daily rate text after the h2 element:

```
<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">JIG SAW</h2>Daily Rate: $14.00
```

I thought I could use `:after` or `::after` but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can wrap both of the elements in a div (if it is already wrapped in a div call your class and just wrap your text in span) or wrap the text in a span and then call it from there in css display:none; . Let me know if this helps

```css
.wrapper span {display: none;}



span {display: none;}




.wrapper2 > h3 {font-size: 25px;}

.wrapper2 {font-size: 0px;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">JIG SAW</h2>
<span>Daily Rate: $14.00</span>
</div>


<!--Another way-->

<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">JIG SAW</h2>
<span>Daily Rate: $14.00</span>


<!--Another way Assigning fontsize to 0 on a the div wrapper-->

<div class="wrapper2">
<h3 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">JIG SAW</h3>
Daily Rate: $14.00
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there another way to go about it if I'm unable to manipulate the HTML?

Comment: Yes theres another way by assigning your div wrapper font-size to 0 then assign a font size on your h2 to whatever you want.

Comment: I updataed the code above those are the 3 things you can hide your text.